# ActionBar Compat Dropdown layout on item click

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

I can use the ActionBar via Library easily. But I don't know how to make visible a Layout when I select an item on Action Bar like this screenShot.
Could someone explain me how to do that?

[image]

Comment: actually I think if I can display a xml layout as dropdown layout for item click , my problem is completely solved !